# Async IO for waiting on POST payload (endpoint to be hit before accessing class members) in Python Flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, python-asyncio, flask-restful

I have two python files ,

1. *factor_main.py*

```
import app
from app import *


class Webhookhandler:

    def __init__(self):
        self.app = app
        self.item = {}


    @staticmethod
    def localize(item):
        return item


class Validate:

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def localize(item):
        print(item)


def main(method):
    localizers = {

        "Webhookhandler": Webhookhandler,
        "Validate": Validate
    }

    return localizers[method]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
    w = main("Webhookhandler")
    print(w.item)
    v = main("Validate")
```

2. *app.py*

```
from flask import Flask, request
from factory_main import *
import asyncio
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/data', methods=["POST"])
def parse_request():
    item = ""
    Webhookhandler.localize(item)
    webhook_data = request.get_json()
    alert_severity = ""
    alert_name = webhook_data['name']
    for i in webhook_data['fields']:
        if i['key'] == 'severity':
            alert_severity = i['value']
    item = {"alertName": alert_name, "alertSeverity": alert_severity}
    Webhookhandler.localize(item)
    return "SUCCESS!"
```

So what I'm trying to achieve here is , I'm trying to send a POST request from POSTMAN with a payload , read it from the Webhookhandler and only extract the required part and send it to the validate class to validate it in terms of length etc , also i'm trying to do all this with respect to factory approach. The problem here is ,i think i need to use async and await to wait until the POST payload (/data endpoint is hit) so that my item and other values will be populated since all these values are not accessible and mostly returning NULL but do not know where. I have just used asyncio.sleep() but I guess it doesn't serve the purpose here. Is my approach wrong or is there any better approach to achieve this ?

Comment: You've got a lot of issues here.  Might I enquire as to your experience with flask and webservers?

Comment: Thanks for the response @JamieMarshall,  I have built a few small flask apps and deployed it on heroku using gunicorn. I know it's not even close to being a decent code structure but i'm always keen to learn and improve.

Comment: So number 1, you need to use ASGI, to really get off the ground with asyncio, not WISGI (`gunicorn`).  Despite what many will tell you, `asyncio`, does actually use multi-threading to accomplish its work.  So, you may not want to think about that just yet. 
 Also, I think whatever goal, your trying to accomplish in the end maybe easier accomplished in other ways.  As I'm reading it now, I don't see a problem with what you're doing, so I'm wondering 1. where your actual error is and 2. What is the actual goal?

Comment: The actual goal here is to read from a POSTMAN POST request with a dummy payload , filter out only the required fields from that payload , validate it using regex or other means and insert it to a database table preferably DynamoDB using boto3.
However , when I first run the server , the values are usually null and I want those values to wait on the /data endpoint to be hit and then be populated so await on endpoint being hit is what i've understood reading the official asyncio docs and also trying to do this using the factory approach which is proving to be a good challenge.

Comment: Got it, so `However , when I first run the server , the values are usually null and I want those values to wait on the /data endpoint to be hit and then be populated`  I don't see anything in your code that would tell me that's what you're doing.  I see an endpoint that looks coded right IMAO, and a `factor_main.py` that is full of helpers.  From what you've provided your app works in this way, 1. it starts the server, 2. it does nothing till it receives a post request, 3. it executes the helpers in `factor_main.py` when it receives a post, passing them the payload from the post.

Comment: Other than building your app for you, I can't really begin to resolve your issue, however I can point you in the right direction.  I think you need a loop in `factor_main.main` that constantly polls some kind of data structure (ex. list, dict, etc...) for data.  I think you also need to brush up on flow control in python and maybe debug your code to see the path the main thread is actually taking.  Once you correct some of your more fundamental python issues, I think you'll find you get much more assistance from SO.  Cheers.

Comment: Ok , first of all , i'm not asking you to 'build my app for me' , i'm just asking for inputs. sorry if that caught you on the wrong path but that's not my intention. Appreciate you for taking the time out to respond to my query. Many thanks!!

Comment: I'm trying to pass the item from webhookhandler to the validate class and access it from localize method in the validate class but cannot do so.

Comment: Let me say this another way.  Your code suggests to me that, you're not aware what is in your apps memory.  Thus its going to be very hard to have a conversation about more in-depth issue like, webservers, design patterns, asyncronisity, etc.  Just want to see  you succeed, but I think to do so, you're going to have to nail down some python basics first.  Not trying to be facetious, I think you should look in to how program flow works and try to follow the actual path of your main thread.  Make sure you know what it's doing at every moment, and what's in the memory at every moment.